# how to fetch the area location on the google map using longitutte and latitude in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

show the location of an address in Google Maps.
how it is possble....
how do i get the address on google map..

show the location with covered region ....
help me out....i tried with code but not working for 
me....

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

try {
address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,7);
if (address == null) {
    return null;
}
Address location = address.get(1);
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();

 geo1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                  (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

 return geo1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code show location on Google Maps when you have `longitude` and `latitude`

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Fetch area location : For example: NewYork City...

```
        try {
        Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Address> addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) gCoder
                .getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

            Log.d(addresses.get(0)
                    .getThoroughfare()
                    + " "
                    + addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea()
                    + " "
                    + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()
                    + ", "
                    + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: thanx for help...but i cant understand the use of    Uri.parse .can u explain....

Comment: what you don't understand?

Comment: Uri.parser("geo:0,0?q=" , what is use of it or what is mean of it (geo:0,0?q=).......thanx

Comment: It's syntax, you must pass in longitude and latitude to this action. Please upvote if it help you.

Comment: thanx bro..thanx for help..but sorry bro, right now i have no right provide to up vote any one...once again sorry..

Comment: Hope it help you @Abhay :)

Comment: If this answer helped you then you can accept it as the correct answer for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
  @override

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {  

  if (event.getAction() == 1) {  
   GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),  
  Locale.getDefault());  
 try {  
 List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(  
  p.getLatitudeE6()/ 1E6, p.getLongitudeE6()/ 1E6,1);  

  String add = "";  
 if (addresses.size() > 0) {  
  for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)  
  add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";  
 }  

 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
 } catch (IOException e) {  
 e.printStackTrace();  
 }  
return true;
```